# Servicenow Rest API call to check if credentials are valid

Tags: rest, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am calling **ServiceNow Rest API** for tables in my application. I allow the user to enter their servicenow instance credentials and domain url in my application.

I want to know if there is a **Simple API call** which I can make to ensure that the **credentials entered are valid**.

Currently I am making a call to get **sys_user** table and making the check.

This call seems to take more time. Is there a **simpler REST URL** which I can use here?

```
public static HttpConnectionResponse checkConnection(String host, String username, String password) {
        String CHECK_URL = "/api/now/table/sys_user";
        HttpConnectionResponse response = new HttpConnectionResponse();
        String completeUrl = "https://"+host+CHECK_URL;
        HashMap<String, String> requestHeaders = ConnectionUtils.getDefaultInputHeader();
        Credential credential = ConnectionUtils.populateCredentials(username, password);
        try{
            response = HttpConnectorClient.getMethod(completeUrl, requestHeaders, credential);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I'm looking to do that too. Problem with @TimWoodruff 's answer is that I don't now which table will be used, I have 0 control over ServiceNow Instance so I can't create create scripts/pages. I must use what is available by default in the Rest API. Did you find an answer ?

Comment: No I went with what I posted, the API which I have given as CHECK_URL is an api to get the user from their instance. It's a standard URL , hopefully you can also use the same. Same question I had asked in their community as well. Din't find any other way

Comment: Ok thank you. I resorted do that too because there was no other options. But it bothers me to check connection to a table I am not 100% sure that I have access to.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use any table or record that you've set to be accessible to any authenticated user, then make a REST API call with their credentials as the basic authentication credentials, to that resource? If you get the record rather than "access denied", the creds are valid. :-) 
You could even make a simple UI page, or better yet, a Processor, just for that purpose.

Comment: That's what I am doing currently, looking for a record from sys_user_set with sysparm_limit=1. I wanted to know if there is some method just for this purpose